# pass a db connexion instance to other classes php

Tags: php, mysql, oop

i am trying to make a registration system using PHP OOP but im getting this errors when i excute it

> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\wamp64\www\news\classes\user.php on line 14
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\wamp64\www\news\classes\user.php on line 14

i beleive that my problem is that my calsse can't get the db connection instance even im passing it on intiation. i have 2 classes and a registration page
my first class is dbconnect.php

```
<?php

    include "./config.php";

    class dbconnect{

        public  function __construct(){
            try {
                $conect = new PDO('mysql:host='.SERVER.'; dbname='.DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD); 
                $conect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $conect;

            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

    }


?>
```

my second class is user.php

```
<?php

    class user{
        public  $username;
        public  $connect;

            function __construct($username,$connect){
                $this->username=$username;
                $this->connect=$connect;
            }

            protected function user_exist(){
                $request="SELECT * FROM `users` where username='".$this->username."'";
                $sql=$connect->prepare($request);
                $sql->execute();
                $results = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if(is_array($results)){
                    //echo "utilisateur exist";
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    //echo "utilisateur n'existe pas";
                    return false;
                }           
            }
            public function register($firstname,$lastname,$email,$user,$password){
                if(!($this->user_exist())){
                    $request="INSERT INTO USERS (nom,prenom,email,user,pass,role,statut,date ) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :username, :password, :role,:staut, :now())";
                    $sql = $connect->prepare($request);
                    $sql->bindParam(':fistname', $firstname);
                    $sql->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
                    $sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
                    $sql->bindParam(':username', $username);
                    $sql->bindParam(':password', $password);
                    $sql->bindParam(':role', 'subscriber');
                    $sql->bindParam(':statut', 'waiting for validation');
                    //$sql->bindParam(':date', $date);
                    try{
                        $sql->execute();
                    }
                    catch(Exception $e){
                        if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
                            echo $e;
                        } else {
                            throw $e;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


    } 

?>
```

and then my registration page

```
<?php
    include "classes/dbconnect.php";
    include "classes/user.php";

    if((isset($_POST["submit"]))    and $_POST["verificaation"]=="submit1"){
        $nom        =   $_POST["nom"];
        $prenom     =   $_POST["prenom"];
        $email      =   $_POST["email"];
        $username   =   $_POST["username"];
        $pass       =   $_POST["password"];
        $passver    =   $_POST["passver"];
        $conect=new dbconnect();

        $user= new user($username,$conect->connect);
        $msg=$user->register($nom,$prenom,$email,$user,$pass);
        print_r ($conect);


    }




?>
<form method="post" action="register.php">
<label>Nom</label>
<input type="text" name="nom"/><br />
<label>Prenom</label>
<input type="text" name="prenom"/><br />
<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email"/><br />
<label>Nom d'utilisateur</label>
<input type="text" name="username" /><br />
<label>Mot de passe</label>
<input type="password" name="password" /><br />
<label>Recrivez le mot de passe</label>
<input type="password" name="passver"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="verificaation" value="submit1" />


</form>
```

Comment: `:now()` that's why and `:fistname` and `:staut`. You need to go over your entire code and continue to debug it.

Comment: Should be `$this->connect` not `$connect`.

Comment: this contains too many errors

Comment: Woah,! Errors.  Couple of errors to point out.  Your bind Param placeholders  don't match. Check them well.  Also the function which checks if user exists is wrong.  You know an array can be empty right. Change $connect to, $this->connect in your user exists function. Advice.  Please use an IDE

Comment: You're using placeholder values in one query but not the other. It's extremely important you use placeholder values for any user data you might have, even things that seem harmless like IDs. These are not guaranteed to be under your control, a code change could expose those values to mutation.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: @tadman thank you for your advice, i'm aware that i should hash the password and to add slashes to every entry, im only trying to learn how to work with classes in PHP

Comment: You don't "add slashes to every entry". Do not use `addslashes`, use prepared statements with placeholder values. That will properly escape the string as necessary. In PDO you can actually `execute` with an associative array of all the placeholders in one call, there's no need to spell out each `bindParam` individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**on User.php**, Instead of using :

```
$sql=$connect->prepare($request);
```

Use :

```
$sql=$this->connect->prepare($request);
```

Also, Instead of using :

```
$sql = $connect->prepare($request);
```

Use :

```
$sql = $this->connect->prepare($request);
```